# Apk size supporting multiple screen densities in Android

Tags: android, apk, android-resources

I'm developing an Android app which supports the following densities: ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi. I have my images stored in each folder and scaled up according to the density. My problem is my APK size is about 100 MB, I guess the images of the four resource folders are adding up.

Is there any way to reduce this APK file size? When I tried to upload my app for testing in-app billing, Google Play has a limit of a 50 MB APK, so can't upload.

Why do users need to download APK which has images that they will never use from another resource foler? Any idea?

Comment: 100MB?  Really?  You must have an enormous amount of images!  The first thing I would look at is compression - can you get by with compressing them more?

Comment: If you've compressed the imaged already to 24bit png and still have such an enormous size apk then its better to delete the resources from ldpi and hdpi. Keep only the resources of mdpi and xhdpi. For ldpi and hdpi, the image resources from mdpi will be scaled up or down by Android. Like wise for xxhdpi the resources of xhdpi will be scaled up. Surely your apk size will reduce and it the UI may need minor tweaks in the layout files.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [expansion file](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)? Or try to compress data.

Answer (score 0):

In September 2015 the maximum limit on the Play Store [has been increased to **100 MB**](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/09/support-for-100mb-apks-on-google-play.html), if you need more space you can add up to two 2 GB [expansion files](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) but it's a bit tricky to implement.

Starting July 2016, when you upload an app, Google Play downloads only the part of the APK which has changed, reducing data consumption.

If you think that your problem is caused by the resources, why not to check the size of the `drawable-<density>` folders, just to have the exact idea of how much space every density is taking?

In any case, if you include only the low-resolution resources, on high-resolution devices they will be scaled up appearing blurry, while if you include only high-resolution resources, they will be scaled down on low-resolution devices, increasing the risk of `OutOfMemoryError`s at runtime. In your case a good approach can be to include only the `mdpi` and `xhdpi` resouces: `ldpi` will then be scaled from `mdpi`, and `hdpi` from `xhdpi`.

Also check if you can replace some of your resources with [9-patches](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html) or, even better, with [SVGs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html).

The last solution is to provide different APK for different densities (and screen sizes), as documented [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#CreatingApks).